# Is wifi helps for geolocation coordinates even without connect any access points

Tags: geolocation, wifi, coordinates

I wonder if any device has open it's wifi without connect any access point and is it give some data info for geolocation?

Answer (score 0):

Is the question about positioning with WiFi hot-spots ? Basically its described pretty well in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system

So basically in it, to be ale to determine the location, you must know the positions of the WiFi hotspots beforehand, or at least have a service which has list of hotspots and which could give you the location for the WiFi's you can see.

You don't need to make any connection to the WiFi hotspots, but you simply use the identification they are giving, and passing that information to the part which is determining the position.

In general, you would need to see whether you can find a service you could use from your selected platform, or whether the platform has APIs for using the technology.

In general positioning APIs might use the WiFi information on their cell-based positioning, and on those cases, you wouldn't really need to know anything about the WiFi things in your app.